# Invalid object name even if it exists

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, error-handling

Here is my code:

```
   InitializeComponent();
   SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("data source = DESKTOP-77FA1JE;" +
             "user id = DESKTOP-77FA1JE\\Chanloi" +
             "initial catalog = TransactionProcessingSystem;" +
             "integrated security = SSPI");

   myConnection.Open();

    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from UserAccounts", myConnection);
   SqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

   BindingSource mySource = new BindingSource();
   mySource.DataSource = myReader;

   dataGridView1.DataSource = mySource;

   myConnection.Close();
```

I get this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid object name 'UserAccounts'.'

Comment: Are you sure that your database contains a table with the name `UserAccounts`?

Comment: Check which schema UserAccounts table belong to? You will need to add it to the table.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple - You do not have a table called `UserAccounts` in your database.
Please try `dbo.UserAccounts`

Answer (score 1):

In Such a Case What I Usually Do Is Run This Statment

```
 select name from sys.tables
```

sys.Tables is a System View That Has info About The Existing Tables In Your Db , This Way You Can Check If The Table Already Exists or U Misspelled It's Name or Existed By Another Name , and Even But an if Condition To Execute Your Logic Only If This Table Exists

Also as Other Have Said it's A Good Practice To Put Column Names Between a [] Brackets , and Call It By Schema Name   like dbo.MyTable

Comment: It will be better to include the schema name in the query.  select SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id), name from sys.tables

Answer (score 0):

try this:

select * from dbo.[UserAccounts]

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straightforward. It's telling you that there is no `UserAccounts` table on your database. You can try `dbo.UserAccounts`, but if it fails, check your database first and also make sure you're connecting to right database.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The above exception says that the table UserAccounts does not exist in your database you are connected through your connection string

Answer (score 0):

if the table is created do a local refresh cahce from Edit section and then intellisense and then refresh lcoal cache